# Can you tell what kind of database is the WSDL using?

Tags: database, wsdl

Can you tell what kind of database is the WSDL using? The reason for asking is the 3rd party only give me a url and and didnt tell me anything about the database. I requested them to give me the document to explain a bit but they never did.

I am new in this area and after some research, but i cannot sure what database (oracle?sql?xml?)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name="AccountService" targetNamespace="http:// local host/web/" xmlns:ns1="http://client.local host/web//" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://local host/web/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://local host/web/" xmlns:tns="local host/web/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfAccount">
<xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Account" nillable="true"     type="tns:Account"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Account">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="currentbalance" nillable="true" type="xsd:decimal"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The second question is, can i use .asp call out the element from the database directly?

The last question is, WSDL is just a set of policy (rules) telling the server to generate the result?

Comment: The whole point of giving you a web service end point is that you don't need to know what's behind it.

Comment: the problem is we need to call out one extra element from the database. And they are asking us to pay 65% more. Which this is the other package and 80% of the contents we wont be need (the other 20% is what we ordered). The best they can do is give us a url and try to work on that element on our own. If they are asking 10-20% more than we will pay for it but 65% is just completely out of our budget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A WSDL is a document describing a webservice, listing all the web methods, and their paramaters.  It helps you build a client that can consume the webservice.  It describes how you can communicate with the webservice.  The webservice itself could be implemented anyway the creator wants, with or without a DB.  They aren't related at all.

Comment: so...can this possible for using other language to call out the element we need? Like classic asp...

Comment: Yes, you could invoke a method from the webservice in a variety of languages.  Your real question is "How can I consume this webservice in a classic ASP application?"

Comment: yes, this is what I try to figure for the past week. Would you mind to show me an example please? since all of the example I can found is for asp.net :(

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to determine the internal implementation of a web service solely from it's WSDL.

Answer (score 1):

For your questions:

1. You can't tell what sort of database, or even anything about the back-end of a Web service from the WSDL. It is specifically a descriptive document that shows what types of methods are available. It could be a Java based Web service, .Net, or whatever, and point to what ever database the Web service developer decided to use. The point of having a service model is that a client doesn't really need to know anything about the inner workings of a service it uses, just what functions you can call, and what sort of data it accepts, which is what the WSDL provides.
2. If you are hosting the Web service, then you would have the database and directions to set up the connection string. In that case, your ASP application "could" connect to the database, but it shouldn't, since it would defeat the purpose of having the service in the first place. It's better to update the service to include whatever functions you need. From your request though, it sounds like you have no control over the Web service, so you won't have any connection directly to the database. If the database were on the same network as your service, and there were no firewall policies blocking database connections, you could theoretically connect to the database the service uses. But, again, that would defeat the purpose of having the service.
3. WSDL is just an XML file that describes what the service can do. It doesn't actually do any work. The work is handled when you make an Http request with something like WebClient or HttpClient to a URL passing in the needed information. So, the WSDL may show in XML:

Method URL:

```
http://someURL/UpdateAccounts
```

Accepts Parameters:
Account

Then in your service you would code to post a request to

```
http://someURL/UpdateAccounts
```

passing in Account converted to XML.

Comment: can you point me a direction how to get what kind of services can WSDL provide?

Comment: Here are some overview links about WSDL. I just did a quick search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language, http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl, http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/default.asp and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996486.aspx

Answer (score 0):

WSDL describes only the interface, like the function definition. Not the internals about the service. So no, you can not tell.